# Extending list1 with second list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and am learning it on my own.

I have two lists and I am trying to use the extend function to append the content of `list2` to `list1`:

```
list1 = ['c', 'cpp', 'python', 123, 456]

list2 = [10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10]

list3 = list1.extend(list2)

print list3
```

This gives the output as: **`None`**

However, when I remove `list3` and just use:

```
list1.extend(list2)

print list1
```

It gives the output of:

> `['c', 'cpp', 'python', 123, 456, 2014, 10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10]`

Why is this? What is different in `list3` that it won't provide the same sequence as when I `print list1`?

Comment: Have you reviewed the answers below and found one that meets your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `None` because that's what `extend` is designed to do. One of the nice things about Python is that it's a self-documenting language that can give you information about how to use its built-in functions.

Try this out in your Python interpreter. Make a list:

```
mammals = ['aardvark', 'bear', 'cat']
```

Now write exactly the following, without parentheses or anything. Exactly this:

```
mammals.extend
```

The Python interpreter prints out `mammals.extend`. Not the result of calling `extend`, but the value of `extend` itself.

```
<built-in method extend of list object at 0x102939fc8>
```

That is a string representation of `extend`. We can see that it's a method attached to lists.

Now do this:

```
print(mammals.extend.__doc__)
```

You will get a nice documentation string. All the built-in methods have a `__doc__` attribute that you can print out when you're unsure how something works.

In this case, you'll see the answer to your question.

```
L.extend(iterable) -> None -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
```

This tells us that the result of calling `extend` is `None`.

You can make your own doc strings when you're writing functions. Put your brief documentation into a string on the very first line of a function, and that string will be magically returned whenever you or others using your code invoke `__doc__` on your function. Like this:

```
def double(s):
     """double(s): Returns the concatenation of the string with itself."""
     return s+s

double("banana")        # Test our new function.
print(double.__doc__)   # Get the doc string.
```

You could have invoked `extend` on an empty string, by the way:

```
print([].extend.__doc__)
```

That will give you the same doc string because `extend` is a method of every list.

If you want to glue two lists together, do the following.

```
mammals = ['aardvark', 'bear', 'cat']
more_mammals = ['dog', 'elephant', 'giraffe']
all_mammals = mammals + more_mammals
print(all_mammals)
```

You can use the `+=` operator instead of `extend`. This line:

```
mammals += more_mammals
```

Has the same effect as this line:

```
mammals.extend(more_mammals)
```

Be careful with operations like `+=` that modify lists. This may not always be what you want.

To keep the lists as they are, make a new list with `+`, the concatenation operator, as we saw earlier.

```
all_mammals = mammals + more_mammals
```

If you don't care about the old value of `mammals` and you really want to extend it with `more_mammals`, go ahead and use `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `extend` method modifies the list in-place and doesn't return anything (that is, it returns `None`).

For more info, read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is

```
list3 = list1 + list2
```

`extend` modifies the original list1, it does not return anything